# SQL mariaDB how can i INSERT a value in a specific column and row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, mariadb

How can i insert a value in a specific row and column, i'm able to select row and column using this code and database:

```
cityid  city    lat     lng      sunrise
1      Tokyo    35.6897 139.6922    
2      Jakarta  -6.2146 106.8451    
3      Delhi    28.66   77.23   



$ sql = "SELECT city FROM table_name WHERE cityid = 1;
```

How can i do the same but using instert, code so far:

```
"INSERT INTO table_name (sunrise) WHERE cityid = 1 VALUES ('8:00:9');"
```

Console say:

error.get_excepetion(packet)mysql.connecector.error.progamingError:1064(42000): you have an error in your SQL syntax

By the way i'm using mariaDB

Comment: You also misspelled `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `update`, not `insert`:

```
UPDATE table_name 
    SET sunrise = '08:00:9'
    WHERE cityid = 1;
```

Comment: I can't find any (the search terms match almost all SQL questions), but there must be hundreds of duplicates of this question.

Comment: @Barmar . . . We probably disagree on what a "duplicate question is".  There may be questions that have essentially the same answer, but that is not a duplicate question to me.

Comment: I've seen many questions where someone tried to use `INSERT ... WHERE` when they mean `UPDATE ... WHERE`

Comment: Seen a lot of sql tutorials on how to insert and read data and they don't explain update , if you come from another background the first thing you think is to use INSERT i mean it  make sense that INSERT can insert data