# PHP and SQL: I want to increment the value of a specific user's row but can't make it work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First of all, I'm sorry for my English.
I've read this thread: [Using PDO Prepared Statement and Incrementing a column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284470/using-pdo-prepared-statement-and-incrementing-a-column-value) but didn't see the answer to my problem. I've also seen [SQL mariaDB how can i INSERT a value in a specific column and row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410192/sql-mariadb-how-can-i-insert-a-value-in-a-specific-column-and-row) But both of these gave a solutions to those problems that didn't work for me. What I mean is, my database's row (usersNiv) does not update to +1.

I'm trying to make a calendar where each day has a content. All the contents are hidden except the first day, to see the content of day 2 the user has to press the button "validate" that's inside day 1, to see the content of day 3 the user has to press the button "validate" that's inside day 2, and so on a so forth...
Well, I can't make my code (with php to work, I'm trying first of all to increase the value and then print it, but I can't increase it on my table nor print it). And then with php and in each day put an if with the condition of "if($usersNiv>=1) then show day 2", "if($usersNiv>=2) then show day 3",...

This is the temporary code for index.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION["useruid"])) {
    $usersUid= $_SESSION["useruid"];
    echo '<p>Hello there ' . $usersUid . "</p>";
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=userlog', 'root', '');
$usersUid= $_SESSION["useruid"];

?>
    <div>
        <form action="includes/index.inc.php" method="$_POST">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="niv1 calendar">1
                    <button type="submit" name="Valider"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit,...

        </p>
    </div>
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE usersUid = ?';
$stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$usersUid]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   $usersNiv = $row['usersNiv'];
   print_r($usersNiv);
}
}
```

And here is the code for the index.inc.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=userlog', 'root', '');
$usersUid= $_SESSION["useruid"];
    
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE usersUid = ?';
$stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$usersUid]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
//    echo $row['usersNiv'] . '<br>';
    $usersNiv = $row['usersNiv'];
}

$usersNiv++;

$sql = 'UPDATE userlog SET usersNiv = :usersNiv WHERE usersUid = :usersUid';
$stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['usersNiv' => $usersNiv, 'usersUid' => $usersUid]);

}
else{
    header("location: ../index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

And here is the table with the value I want to increment https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7EAy.png

I've tried what you've seen, I've also tried

```
$sql = 'UPDATE userlog SET usersNiv = usersNiv + 1 WHERE usersUid = :usersUid';

$sql = 'UPDATE userlog SET usersNiv = :usersNiv + 1 WHERE usersUid = :usersUid';
```

And a bunch of other stuff but can't print it nor save the + 1 on my table.
I've even tried $_GET through index.php directly with this:

```
    <?php

if(isset($_GET["submit"])){

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=userlog', 'root', '');
$usersUid= $_SESSION["useruid"];

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE usersUid = ?';
$stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$usersUid]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo $row['usersNiv'] . '<br>';
$usersNiv = $row['usersNiv'];
}


$sql = 'UPDATE users SET usersNiv = usersNiv + 1 WHERE (usersUid = :usersUid)';
$stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['usersUid' => $usersUid]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['usersNiv'] . '<br>';
    $usersNiv = $row['usersNiv'];
    }
}
} else {
    echo "Veuillez vous connectez pour accéder à cette page, s'il vous plait.";
}
?>
```

My problem, is that every time I run the code, my database isn't updated, so usersNiv doesn't go up +1.

I'm sorry if my explanation is confusing. If you need any detail let me know, or if you don't understand something let me know aswell, and I'll try to explain it differently.

Thank you very much!

L. Stioui

Comment: You shouldn't "try" "a bunch of things". You MUST use the only ONE variant, the code from "Using PDO Prepared Statement and Incrementing a column value" answer. And if it doesn't work you must explain, why do you think it doesn't work.

Comment: I see that you `fetch()` rows from an `UPDATE` query. That's not possible, you can only `fetch()` from queries that have results, like `SELECT`. The problem with your question is that it is unclear what your problem is. We cannot run your code, unless we implement your database, so all we can do is visually scan it, and see if it makes sense.